# CakePHP 1.3.7 - Renaming className in Model file breaks login page

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

I have an install of Cake 1.3.7 which I inherited from a previous developer for one of my clients. There is a model that includes the following:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
[. . .]
    'TimeSlot' => array(
        'className' => 'TimeSlot',
        'foreignKey' => 'time_slot',
    ),
[. . .]
```

I have renamed this model and class to OtherInfo, and changed the foreign key to other_info. All the appropriate files exist, the cache files have been refreshed, and I've successfully tested everything. The code above now looks like this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
[. . .]
    'OtherInfo' => array(
        'className' => 'OtherInfo',
        'foreignKey' => 'other_info',
    ),
[. . .]
```

Everything works fine, *until I log out of the software*. At that point, the login page fails to load. Instead it gives me a generic "An Internal Error Has Occurred" message, which assigning a debug value in config.php doesn't seem to help with. However, if I rename className back to TimeSlot, the login page will load and I can log in. Once I'm logged back in, I can then rename className to OtherInfo again and the rest of the software will work just fine.

So I know exactly what line of code is causing the problem, but not why it causes a problem or what to do about it. Does anyone have any advice? I am a total novice in Cake and consider myself having done well for getting this far.

Comment: Did you make any changes in the database, or just renamed this class? Did you find places where this association is used and change them? What's the goal here? The purpose of making this change?

Comment: Yes, the table time_slots was duplicated to other_info, and the time_slot column in the call table was renamed to other_info. All requisite files were copied and modified as required, and again, as long as I'm already logged in, everything works fine. It's seemingly just the login page that's broken, and changing that one entry back to what it was before allows it to work again.

Comment: In that case, what you've got here should be okay, so the problem is in code you haven't shown us. Details of the error that's happening should be in the error log, that would point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution is to delete the contents of the cache directories so that Cake can rebuild them. These directories are in `app/tmp/cache/persistent/` and `app/tmp/cache/models/`